# iPhone Get Nearby Cities

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, foursquare, city

In my application, there is a requirement that when user is filling a form and selects "city" options, a new screen should be launched, providing an option to search city and a pre-filled list of near-by cities.I searched for Google and Foursquare web-service to get nearby cities, but didn't find any relevant one.

I also tried using this service:
http://api.geonames.org/cities?north=21.226303&south=15.820897&east=76.550503&west=71.145097&lang=en&username=myusername

But it does not always retrieve relevant data.

Please let me know how can I achieve this. Thanks in advance :)